How to format user input double in TextField as and when being entered by user in Flutter?
I'm trying to display the user input double (may be without decimal dot and that follows) number as a formatted value e.g. 123456789012.1234 as 12345,67,89,012.1234 using not the western numbering system, but using Indian Subcontinent numbering system as shown. Preferably, no commas after crore.
With the intl package, I could display formatted output, but I also need to format the input being entered by the user in the text input filed. And this I could not manage to get working.
The minimal code:
I've written the following minimal code to show my problem. Here, as I enter 123 an then 4 a comma appears at the correct place (i.e. 1,234) but then when I enter the fifth digit i.e. 5 in succession, only 0 is displayed which is erroneous.
How can I fix this?
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

final _controller = TextEditingController();

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('intl Formatter With Formatted Text Field'),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: TextField(
            controller: _controller,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            onChanged: (value) {
              NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat("#,##,##,###.########");
              final formattedValue =
                  numberFormat.format(double.tryParse(value) ?? 0.0);
              _controller.value = TextEditingValue(
                text: formattedValue,
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


To format user input in Flutter, you will need to create a custom formatter. This approach will give you more control.

What I needed was to format the input double value in TextField to be shown in Indian Numbering Format. In the question I posted my minimal code which tried to do so incompletely. With the help form the answer from @frankenapps here, and my trial and errors, I have finally managed to get what I wanted.
More suggestions to improve the code or completely new answer are welcome.
The Final Code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

final _controller = TextEditingController();

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class RememberMyValue {
  static String value_previous_or_this_instance = "";
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  String parseMyNumber(String str) {
    // Function to parse only positive numbers (without any prefix):
    RegExp myNumber01 = RegExp(r'^[0-9]+$');
    RegExp myNumber02 = RegExp(r'^[0-9]+\.$');
    RegExp myNumber03 = RegExp(r'^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$');

    NumberFormat numberFormat01_and_02 = NumberFormat("#,##,##,###");
    // The result of eight #s after the decimal point is that users will be able
    // to input only eight digits after decimal.
    NumberFormat numberFormat03 = NumberFormat("#,##,##,###.########");
    // We want to stop taking digits after 8 digits succeding the decimal dot
    // in the user input in consistent with the numberFormat03 formatting. We
    // declare the following constant for that.
    const int maxDigitsAfterDecimalPeroid = 8;
    const int countOfAPeriod = 1;

    print("########## str=$str");
    String lastChar = "";
    String extractedString = "";

    int digitsBeforePeriod = str.indexOf(".");
    if (str.length >
        digitsBeforePeriod + countOfAPeriod + maxDigitsAfterDecimalPeroid) {
      extractedString = str.substring(
          0, str.indexOf(".") + (maxDigitsAfterDecimalPeroid + 1));
      str = extractedString;
    }

    print("########## extracted_string=$extractedString");

    if (str.isEmpty) {
      return "";
    }

    if (myNumber01.hasMatch(str)) {
      return numberFormat01_and_02.format(int.parse(str));
    } else {
      if (myNumber02.hasMatch(str)) {
        // Here str.replaceAll(".", "") chops the trailing dot from the input, and
        // finally the return statement is interpolated such that there is a dot
        // appended at the end of the number.
        return "${numberFormat01_and_02.format(int.parse(str.replaceAll(".", "")))}.";
      } else {
        if (myNumber03.hasMatch(str)) {
          lastChar = str[str.length - 1];
          print("########## lastChar=$lastChar");
          if (lastChar == "0") {
            String subStringBeforePeriod = "";
            String subStringAfterPeriod = "";
            String tmpStr = "";

            int indexOfPeriod = str.indexOf(".");

            subStringBeforePeriod = str.substring(0, indexOfPeriod);
            print("########## subStringBeforePeriod=$subStringBeforePeriod");
            subStringAfterPeriod = str.substring(indexOfPeriod + 1, str.length);
            print("########## subStringAfterPeriod=$subStringAfterPeriod");

            print("########## str with last char possibly = $str");
            // return numberFormat03.format(double.parse(str)) + lastChar;
            tmpStr =
                numberFormat01_and_02.format(int.parse(subStringBeforePeriod));
            print("tmpStr=$tmpStr");
            // return numberFormat03.format(double.parse(str)) + lastChar;
            return "${tmpStr}.${subStringAfterPeriod}";
          }
          return numberFormat03.format(double.parse(str));
        } else {
          return "NaN";
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('intl Formatter With Formatted Text Field'),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: TextField(
            controller: _controller,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            onChanged: (value) {
              print("########## value=$value");
              value = value.replaceAll(",", "");

              String myFormattedNumber = "";
              myFormattedNumber = parseMyNumber(value);
              if (myFormattedNumber != "NaN") {
                RememberMyValue.value_previous_or_this_instance =
                    myFormattedNumber;
                print(
                    "########## value_previous_or_this_instance = ${RememberMyValue.value_previous_or_this_instance}");
              } else {
                print("########## NaN");
              }

              _controller.value = TextEditingValue(
                text: RememberMyValue.value_previous_or_this_instance,
              );
              print("########## _controller.text = ${_controller.text}");
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Snapshot:


The issue with your current code is that the value contains a comma (,) after entering 1234. When entering the next character (e.g. 5) 1,2345 is passed to double.tryParse which fails to parse the value, because it contains a comma and the parser only respects dots (.) for separating decimal places.
One option to circumvent this is to remove all commas before passing the value to double.tryParse, like so:
value = value.replaceAll(",", "");

Here is dart.dev sample.

With this solution, the commas appear at the right positions. But, I couldn't complete my double number with decimal and following digits. The TextField doesn't take the dot '.' in the input. Any solution to that? (Thank you for your answer that has partially solved my problem.)

Thanks again for your solution. +1 . With the help of your answer I have managed to get what I needed with additional codes as you can find in my answer.
